# how to query array use to jquery ui tabs?

Tags: codeigniter

[image: http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/v/1291812_726798364014050_1048588136_n.jpg?oh=a3d67e861bd9932a6a19e57819d2baa2&oe=5233F729&__gda__=1379199229_33f351e1d3876f61503ffe0097f059eb]

I want to query to array as:

```
Array ( [0] => Array 
( [0] => Array ([cid] => 12 [sid] => 1 [category_name] => กาแฟ [mid] => 7 [menu_name] => เอสเพรสโซ่ (ร้อน) [price] => 50 )
 [1] => Array ( [cid] => 12 [sid] => 1 [category_name] => กาแฟ [mid] => 9 [menu_name] => มอคค่า (ร้อน) [price] => 50 )
)
 [1] =>Array ( [0]=> Array ( [cid] => 14 [sid] => 1 [category_name] => โกโก้ & ชา [mid] => 8 [menu_name] => โกโก้ (เย็น) [price] => 60 )

 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure exactly what you mean but I believe youre trying to grab data from your array to insert into ui tabs. This is what I would do in MVC:

View:

```
<li class="tab" id=""><a href="#<?php echo $variable; ?>">Test</a></li>
<li class="tab" id=""><a href="#<?php echo $variable; ?>">Test</a></li>
<li class="tab" id=""><a href="#<?php echo $variable; ?>">Test</a></li>
<li class="tab" id=""><a href="#<?php echo $variable; ?>">Test</a></li>
<li class="tab" id=""><a href="#<?php echo $variable; ?>">Test</a></li>
```

Controller:

```
function expand_staff_info($staff_info) {
   $data = $this->Model_request->getData();
   $this->load->view('agents/view_staff_info', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
 function getData() {
  $array = array(..... YOUR ARRAY ......);
  $data;
   foreach ($array as $row) {
     foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        $data[$key] = $val;
     }
   }
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: function menu()
 {
  $this->db->from('menu');
  $this->db->where('menu.sid','1');

  $menu=$this->db->get();
  //return $menu->result_array();


    $data;
     foreach ($menu->result_array() as $row) {
       foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
          $data[$key] = $val;
        }
     }
    return $data;


 }

result:Array ( [mid] => 9 [sid] => 1 [menu_name] => มอคค่า (ร้อน) [cid] => 12 [price] => 50 )